# Changing a variable in different function using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I have got some C code and I am not allowed to change the structure. I have got an array called arr in my main function:

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4}
```

I have to change the values of this array in another function. Which is called inside the main function using:

```
change_array(arr);
```

The change_array method is implemented in another .c file. I am only allowed to make changes inside the change_array function.

```
void change_array(void *the_array)
{

}
```

In this function I want to change the values from arr. I found out that i can get the first value of the array using:

```
int first_value = *(int*)the_array;
```

And I can get the location of the first value using:

```
int location = the_array;
```

I tried to change the values with:

```
*the_array = 1;
```

but that did not solve my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You need the size/length of the array as well

Comment: void is not a type to change its value. You need to cast the_array to int pointer. So, `*(int *) the_array = 1` should work. But I wonder why not making `change_array(int *the_array)` instead.

Comment: copy the_array to an int *p on the stack,  Then p[x] = newvalue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C programming language, the address of the array is the address of the first element.

1. *the_array points to the first element (value 1 in your case). You need to use [] or [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) to move around the array.
2. You also need the size of the array so you can iterate the array without going out of bounds.

Here is an example:

```
void change_array(void *the_array, int size)
{
   int a = 0, b = 0, i = 0;

   // how to set and iterate
   for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       ((int*)the_array)[i] = i;
   }

   // how to get
   a = ((int*)the_array)[0];
   b = ((int*)the_array)[1];
   b = *((int*)the_array + 1); // same as the line before. Example of pointer arithmetic
}
```

Comment: I get and error for the last line: "invalid use of void expression"

Comment: You need to change it to `((int *)the_array)[0]`

Comment: True, revised @JoeLiBuDa

Answer (score 3):

You can create an int pointer in your change_array() function and modify the values through that as seen below. This works because the pointer you are passed is just the memory address of the first element in the array. So by assigning another pointer - of the appropriate type - to that same location, you can modify the original values directly. That is, any change you make to that memory location in your function will also change the original array because they occupy the same place in memory.

As pointed out by others, you will have no way of knowing the size of the array that they are passing you. You mentioned not being able to change the calling code, so I assume that won't be an option for you. Assuming your function will only be called with a fixed size is fragile, but it should still work for you.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void change_array( void * the_array );

int main()
{
int arr[ 4 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

printf( "Before:\n%d | %d | %d | %d\n", arr[ 0 ], arr[ 1 ], arr[ 2 ], arr[ 3 ] );
change_array( arr );
printf( "After:\n%d | %d | %d | %d\n", arr[ 0 ], arr[ 1 ], arr[ 2 ], arr[ 3 ] );

return( 0 );
}

void change_array( void * the_array )
{
int * arr_ptr = the_array; //NOTE: This is implicitly converting the void * to an int *
printf( "In the changing function:\n%d | %d | %d | %d\n", arr_ptr[ 0 ], arr_ptr[ 1 ], arr_ptr[ 2 ], arr_ptr[ 3 ] );
arr_ptr[ 0 ]  = 5;
arr_ptr[ 1 ]  = 6;
arr_ptr[ 2 ]  = 7;
arr_ptr[ 3 ]  = 8;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://codepad.org/6PXBeZlY

Comment: The cast is redundant; `int *arr_ptr = the_array;` is sufficient (and in fact better).

Comment: @matt I agree it is redundant, but I'm not aware of any downsides to using it and I feel it provides a little more clarity as to what's being done.

Comment: Using the cast may hide an error if types are later changed ; in general it's good to avoid casts as they suppress important warnings

Comment: To "*provides a little more clarity as to what's being done*" you are free to add as many comments to your code as you feel are necessary to understand it. In C casting in is seldom necessary. And why write unnecessary code? It just confuses, as the reader might ask herself: "Why did she do this, where it seems to **not** be necessary here? Am I missing soemthing"!

Comment: @Matt Because the parameter is a void *, an implicit cast to any type is not going to provide an error. An error would be hidden if the thing being casted had an explicit type associated with it. That being said, I went ahead and removed my cast.

Comment: @alk If I were writing this code in my production environment, I wouldn't need a cast of any sort as my function would require the int * directly instead of just taking a void *. Because I can't write any sort of usage requirements for the function, I find that the cast provides slightly more explicit clarity as to how the function expects to be called.